# According to Deuteronomy 1:39 and Numbers 32:11 someone suggesting baptism should be given to only age 20 or above. What age is right for Baptism?

Tags: deuteronomy, numbers, baptism, age

The argument is given that children below 20 can not be accountable as per God in Deut. 1:39. On that basis, the repentance below age 20 should not be acceptable therefore giving baptism below 20 is against God. Although we don't find any age mention for baptism in New Testament.

Deut. 1:39

> Moreover your little ones, which ye said should be a prey, and your children, **which in that day had no knowledge between good and evil**, they shall go in thither, and unto them will I give it, and they shall possess it.

Numbers 32:11

> Surely none of the men that came up out of Egypt, from twenty years old and upward, shall see the land which I sware unto Abraham, unto Isaac, and unto Jacob; because they have not wholly followed me:

Comment: There is no mention of the age of 20 in the text you quote (Deuteronomy 1:39). Could you please reference where you are getting that age from, please.  Numbers 32:11 ?

Comment: Numbers 1:3 states the age of 20 as  being _twenty years old and above—_ **all who are able to go to war_**. Being old enough to be a soldier capable of killing is not the same as being old enough to repent and to trust in Christ by faith, thence to be baptised.

Comment: You state _cannot be accountable_. Where do you get that from ?

Comment: Please include explicit quotations of the verses you mention. Otherwise, every reader has to individually look up what these verses say. That's an unnecessary inconvenience and, since many won't bother to do that, they aren't going to consider answering your question.

Comment: @RayButterworth good call; I added the text of the verses. Anand, welcome to the site! If you do not like the edits I made to you question I can roll them back.

Comment: I have seen youtube video on baptism in Indian language - hindi. The speaker (He called himself Apostle) said God did not kill Israelites age below 20 "children who do not yet know good from bad". The speaker said God called them "children" who are below age 20 who have no right understanding of good from evil. He is suggesting the same principle we should apply today and forbid children below 20 from baptism.

Answer (score 3):

The Bible does not explicitly state an age at which baptism is to occur.

We are told:

- Jesus was about 30 years of age when baptized (Luke 3:23)
- Men entered the service in the tabernacle at 30  years of age (Numbers 4:3)

But neither gives a command that can explicitly answer the question in the OP.

Deut. 1:39 does specify that young children do not have knowledge between good & evil (although it does not specify how young).

John the Baptist (and others) taught that baptism followed repentance:

> John did baptize in the wilderness, and preach the baptism of repentance for the remission of sins. (Mark 1:4)

It is understandable, then, that John was perplexed when Jesus sought baptism at John's hand. Jesus explained the need for His own baptism in Matthew 3:15 - to fulfill all righteousness, or to be obedient. Jesus also, though free from sin, offered an example for His disciples to follow (e.g. John 13:15)

--

**Conclusion**

The Bible's teachings on baptism unto repentance for the remission of sins, and its teaching that little children do not have the ability to choose evil (and therefore have no sins to remit) can be reasonably interpreted to state that little children are not accountable and do not need baptism.

A precise age of accountability is not specified in the Biblical text, though a variety of ages are given in extra-Biblical texts.

Comment: This is about the best we can do - we are not told - People should be baptized when they understand and want to be. +1.

Answer (score 0):

First, let us look at the context of the scriptures quoted in the question.

Deuteronomy 1:39 is retelling the complaints of those coming out of Egypt and how they were fearful for their children. Moses then speaks about how those children who had not experienced the "good life" of living in Egypt would be the ones entering the Promised Land. When it mentions that they "had no knowledge between good and evil", Moses is talking about these children not having been corrupted by the Egyptian lifestyle that their parents had been and is seen by their wanting to go back to Egypt (see Exodus 16:3).

Numbers 23:11 is again retelling Jehovah God's judgment on the complaining Israelites and because of their stubbornness those "twenty years old and upward" would not enter the Promised Land.

Both of these scriptures are accounts happening centuries before baptism began as a practice.

Now the main question is, What age is right for baptism?

As others have mentioned in their comments/answers, no age is given as to when baptism should occur. But the scriptures are not completely silent on the matter. Note for example Acts 2:14, 22, 38, 41 [KJV]:

> <sup>**14**</sup> But Peter, standing up with the eleven, lifted up his voice, and said unto them, Ye men of Judaea, and all ye that dwell at Jerusalem, be this known unto you, and **hearken to my words**:
>
> <sup>**22**</sup> Ye men of Israel, **hear these words**; Jesus of Nazareth, a man approved of God among you by miracles and wonders and signs, which God did by him in the midst of you, **as ye yourselves also know**:
>
> <sup>**38**</sup> Then Peter said unto them, **Repent**, and be baptized every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ for the remission of sins, and ye shall receive the gift of the Holy Ghost.
>
> <sup>**41**</sup> Then they that gladly received his word were baptized: and the same day there were added unto them about three thousand souls.

From this account we can see that Peter was addressing those that **heard** his words, **knew** about Jesus, **repented** of their sins, and were baptized. Can this be applied to a child?

The child, or anyone choosing to become a follower of Christ, must **come to know** who Jesus Christ is and what role he plays in the disciple's life. He/she must also **believe** that which they have come to know they can be saved from a sinful course and **repent** from that course of life. Then the individual can make a conscious, whole-hearted decision to dedicate their life to Jehovah God and follow a life course similar to Jesus Christ.